# How to identify/get called client id when using simultaneous dialing in Twilio

Tags: android, twilio, voip

If I use simultaneous dialing with Twilio as so:

```
<Response>
<Dial>
<Client>Jenny</Client>
<Client>Tom</Client>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

And Jenny picks up, how do I programatically identify it is Jenny that picked up?

Comment: please check below answer and accept that answer if its correct

Answer (score 3):

Give a answer url to each client as below

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
       <Client url="answer_url.php?client_name=jenny">Jenny</Client>
       <Client url="answer_url.php?client_name=tom">Tom</Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

**answer_url.php**

```
<Response>
     <Say voice="woman">
        <?php echo $_REQUEST["client_name"]." has answered call"; ?>
     </Say>
</Response>
```

answer_url.php will be executed before connecting to client when call has been answered.

Comment: Hi Ijas, Very useful insight. I will accept this as the correct answer as it did answer the question. But I specifically want the caller to identify the called party without using the server (e.g. Using the Connection variable etc.) . Also, the url only takes a Twiml url. Is there a solution for it?

Comment: Hi Ijas, This method informs the receivers of who is calling them. I am trying to inform the sender of which receiver picked up. Thanks

Comment: Sorry @Pacemaker , i misunderstood. This can be done using API. But it needs a server